# Does false sharing occur in this read-only multithreading situation?

Tags: c++, caching

```cpp
Matrix4X4* EightMatrix;

void Calculate(const Matrix4X4* eightMatirx)
{
    //eightMatirx is only read for calculating something   
}
```

The `Calculate` function is concurrently executed on multiple threads. I know false sharing occurs when multiple processors access data on the same cache line. In my situation, all threads access the same memory location (`eightMatrix`). But `eightMatrix` isn't written by threads, only read, so it doesn't require cache coherency. But I'm worried about false sharing. Does it occur in this scenario?

Comment: False sharing is only an issue if at least one thread is writing to the shared memory. If all threads are read-only, then sharing memory is no problem. This applies to both false and true sharing.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I appreciate your informative comment, though I am not the OP. Then, does false sharing also occur when only one thread is reading and other threads are writing?

Comment: @SmartHumanism: Yes. [False sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) occurs when several threads access the same cache line and at least one thread is writing.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you very much for your help. :)

I, by mistake, asked a question in the opposite way(whether false sharing occurs when only one thread is writing, not reading, and other threads are reading) but your answer also resolves that.

I hope you have a good day.